# Selecting a set of attractors among available attractors

Tags: anylogic

i want to make Pedestrians to select a specific attractors once they enter a waiting area where this area is a waiting area , this area has many attractors , how that can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pedWait block has that option clearly defined:
you can choose a customer attractor choice and use areaNode local variable in the attractor choice in order to get the attractor you want. In this example i choose the first attractor (with index 0), but you will have to create your own logic in order to decide what is the suitable attractor for your incoming agent.

[image]